# for prime ideals, the intersection of the squares is the square of the intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Here is something that i proved and i would appreciate feedback on my proof:

> Proposition: Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring and $p,q \in \operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Then $p^2 \cap q^2 = (p\cap q)^2$.

Proof: $(\Rightarrow)$: let $x \in p^2 \cap q^2$. Then $x = y^2=z^2$ with $y \in p, z \in q$. Then $y^2-z^2=0 \in q$. Hence $y^2 \in q$ and so $y \in q$ which finally shows $y \in p \cap q$. Since $x = y^2$, this shows that $x \in (p \cap q)^2$. $(\Leftarrow)$ Take $x \in (p \cap q)^2$, thus $x=y^2$ with $y \in p \cap q$. Then $x=y^2 \in p^2 \cap q^2$.

Edit:

As Berci's answer shows, my proof is incorrect. Certainly we have $(p\cap q)^2 \subset p^2 \cap q^2$. The question now is whether the reverse inclusion holds.

Comment: @YACP: you mean that if i have primes that they satisfy equality?

Comment: No, I mean the contrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly.

The square of an ideal $I$ contains the sums of products $xy$ where $x,y\in I$. But I think, the proof can be reformulated accordingly..

(Well, actually, if $\exists 1/2\in A$, then the elements $x^2$ for all $x\in I$ *generate* $I^2$..)

Comment: on a second thought, if $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are generators of $p$, then in general the generators of $p^2$ are all terms of the form $x_i x_j$, right? So how can we see your statement in parenthesis?

Comment: I was considering *all* elements $x$ of $I$, and was thinking about the classical trick: $2xy=(x+y)^2-x^2-y^2$.

Comment: @Berci: Wow, that looks great :) But $2$ must be a unit, right?